# How do I track cardinality in a for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

[image]I have an array of elements that each have either a 1 or 0.  I want to go through every element and count which elements have the most 1s.

So I have three fields:

id, question, and yesno

the values look like this:

```
1,1,0
1,2,0
1,3,1
1,4,0
1,5,1
2,1,0
2,2,1
2,3,1
2,4,0
2,5,1
3,1,0
3,2,1
3,3,1
3,4,0
3,5,1
```

That's the gist of it.  Now, I want to count which elements in the middle column, have the most 1s in the third column.  In another way of explaining it.  I want to iterate through the for loop and count how many times the middle numbers are "1".  Later, I am going to sort to figure out which one has the most.  How do I do this type of iteration?

Please ask questions if it is confusing! I am confused myself...!

Comment: What do you want once you count number of times middle column is "1" ?

Comment: Basically, I want to figure out which of the middle columns is "1" the most.  If you notice, the middle column cycles, 12345,12345,12345. In other words, if you check out the field names, there's question (middle column) and yes/no (represented by 1 or 0).  I want to find out which questions are "yes" the most.  Meaning, which of the 12345, has the most 1s.

Comment: I added an image, it should be helpful

Comment: I've added [tag:mysql] tag for you, because that looks like phpMyAdmin interface :)

Comment: So your data are in a database? If so, please edit your question and add this relevant information to it. This way it looks like your data is apriori an accosiative PHP array.

Answer (score 4):

If this is inside a database, you can use this SQL:

```
SELECT question_id, SUM(value = 1) AS value
FROM mytable
GROUP BY question_id
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

1. The `SUM(value = 1)` counts the occurrences of each `yesno` value equals 1;
2. Using `GROUP BY question_id` it counts #1 per question
3. Then you order it based on number of occurrences in descending order (first is highest)
4. Take the first item.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this? How does it work? And also, would this be the best way to do it? Rather than running a php for loop?

Comment: @DanielFein And yes, database manipulation is much better done in the database than in PHP, as long as it's reasonably possible ;)

Comment: That seems really smart! Thank you! How do you write this as a query string? Can I just put that in one line?

Comment: @DanielFein You can run this inside phpMyAdmin and check the results.

Comment: @DanielFein Yes, whitespace in MySQL queries is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you still prefered to do it in PHP:

```
$counts=array();
foreach($arr as $v) @$counts[$v['movie_id']]+=$v['value'];
```

We make an empty array, and then add `$v['value']` to the item with key `$v['movie_id']` in this array. If the key doesn't exists yet, it is created with value `0`, and depending on your PHP settings, a Notice is displayed. The at-sign `@` placed in front of a PHP command suppresses notices and warnings generated in that line.

Comment: What will this return? I've never seen the @ symbol or the double brackets like that before.

Comment: Edited. Better? Yeah, and no "double brackets" exist, they are just two "single brackets" next to each other.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, just to be clear, should I replace movie_id with question_id?

Comment: You want there the thing that is voted for, i.e., if people vote for movies and you want to pick up the best movie, you want `movie_id`.